how to solve: Could not resolve "zone.js/node"
I'm using Angular v17 and I got this error when building the app
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "zone.js/node"

    angular:polyfills-server:angular:polyfills-server:1:7:
      1 │ import 'zone.js/node';
        ╵        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "zone.js/node" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error and leave the unresolved path in the bundle.

I see this comment

There is likely a pnp.cjs file on your computer.

but I searched for such a file (also .pnp.cjs), but there is no such a file in the whole system at all.

What about just doing what it says in the error message? "You can mark the path "zone.js/node" as external to exclude it from the bundle"

For Angular 18.1.4:

npm install zone.js
add the following in tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "zone.js/node": ["node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js"]
    }
  }
}

